# Obter caminho onde arquivo python é chamado

Tags: python, arquivo, path

Eu criei um arquivo python e deixei ele disponível para acessar de todo local no sistema, porem, para muitas aplicações preciso do caminho onde foi chamado o arquivo python pelo sistema, mas não encontrei na internet forma alguma de obter este valor, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O ideal seria você colocar parte do seu código pra ajudar na identificação de problemas/soluções (pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seria algo como: `os.path.realpath(__file__)` ??

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método **getcwd** da biblioteca **os**

Ele retorna o seu diretório de trabalho atual

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IxhJ/14)

Se quiser ler um pouco mais: [os.getcwd](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm)

Comment: Obrigado, Grato.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas